# Write full HTTP POST request packet

Tags: web-services, soap, arduino, http-post

I need to write a full http request for invoke a SOAP service. I don't have libraries for soap request so i need to write full HTTP packet. this is how i've proceeded (i'm programming an arduino board):

```
String body = HttpRequestBody("33", "77%");

client.println("POST /dataserver HTTP/1.1");
client.println("Accept: text/xml, multipart/related");
client.println("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
client.println("SOAPAction: \"http://example.com/Functions/SendDataRequest\"");
client.println("User-Agent: Arduino WiFiShield");
client.println("Content-Length: "+body.length());
client.println("Host: arduino-data-server.appspot.com/dataserver");
client.println("Connection: Keep-Alive");
client.println();
client.println(body);
```

client represent connection to my webservice. This is HttpRequestBody function:

```
String HttpRequestBody(String v1, String v2) {
Serial.println("Generating xml message...");
String res = "";
res += "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n\r";
res +="<S:Envelope xmlns:S=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"\n\r";
res +="<S:Body>\n\r";
res +="<ns2:sendData xmlsn:ns2=\"http://example.com\">\n\r";
res +="<arg0>"+v1+"</arg0>\n\r";
res +="<arg1>"+v2+"</arg1>\n\r";
res +="</ns2:sendData>\n\r";
res +="</S:Body>\n\r";
res +="</S:Envelope>\n\r";
Serial.println(res);

return  res;
}
```

But something gone wrong and i can't contact webserver. Webserver works and it's reacable, because if i change POST into GET, on webservice log, i see connection. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

In HttpRequestBody you are allocating: `String res = "";` and then updating it.  Finally, you return `res`.  But, `res` was allocated on the stack of HttpRequestBody (??), you are **NOT** guaranteed that it will be there after HttpRequestbody terminates.

You probably need to do the C++ equivalent of malloc used in C code, in order to ensure that res is on the heap and does not get freed.